# Unable to delete email from gmail inbox

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Hello I wrote the following code

```
    string fetchdata;

size_t write_data(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up) {
    fetchdata.append((char*)buf, size*nmemb);
    return size*nmemb;
}

void main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "ghtyyuu3@gmail.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxxxxx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX;UID=1");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "UID STORE 1 +Flags \DELETE");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",

        curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    std::ofstream outfile("/home/ilia/Desktop/fetched.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    outfile << fetchdata;
    outfile.close();
}
```

I manage to read the mail into a text file but I am unable to delete the mail (gmail settings to delete the mail already set)

I probably have an error in:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "UID STORE 1 +Flags \DELETE");
```

While the CURL itself dont give me an error the mail is still not deleted
Please help

Comment: `While the CURL itself dont give me an error the mail is still not deleted Please help`

Full error will be helpful.

Comment: I have no error the curl write me it has successfully finnished

Comment: For now I used curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/Inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X "STORE 1 +Flags \Deleted" and curl --url "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993/Inbox;UID=1" --user "user:password" -X "EXPUNGE" thrugh linux .sh file and indeed it delete my email it would be nice to know how to transport those commands into C++

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in string constants. Try `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "UID STORE 1 +Flags \\Deleted");` instead.

Comment: Alternatively you can use C++11 [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) like `R"(so)"`